# Multipage Textbox within Userform to Display value from Combobox selection

Tags: vba, excel

as simple as it seems I can't figure out how to display the value selected from page1 Combo Box to display in page2 Text Box within the userform.

Code I've Tried:

```
Private Sub textbox_Change()
 Me.textbox.Text = Me.combobox.Value
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub textbox_Change()
 Me.textbox.Text = Me.combobox.Text
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please provide more details about your UserForm. Page1? Page2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MultiPage` doesn't matter. Just refer to every control by its codename, as you currently seem to be doing.

The problem is you ask for "*changing combobox updates textbox*" and your code is the opposite way around, i.e. *changing your textbox updates your combobox*. So try this instead:

```
Private Sub combobox_Change()
    textbox.Value = combobox.Value
End Sub
```

---

[image]
[image]